# Making div content responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design, css

My content isn't responsive at the moment. I've tested it on iPhone and the text goes over the screen.

I've changed the CSS of my container to:

```
#container2 {
    width: 960px; 
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

When I test it after the change, the content disappears. I read that putting max-width:90%; would allow it to not exceed the boundary width (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design) but obviously it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would look at your margins `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -480px` might be redundant, but  can't tell without seeing your context. For a responsive page it would be more useful to use percentage rather than pixel size definitions. And you might want to look into CSS media queries

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this css:

```
/* Show in default resolution screen*/
#container2 {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

/* If in mobile screen with maximum width 479px. The iPhone screen resolution is 320x480 px (except iPhone4, 640x960) */    
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    #container2 { width: 90%; }
}
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/CG9WN/

Comment: Maybe better if you change the code in this way:

 #container2 {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height: 1.4em;
 }

Answer (score 8):

Not a lot to go on there, but I think what you're looking for is to flip the `width` and `max-width` values:

```
#container2 {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 960px;
  /* etc, etc... */
}
```

That'll give you a container that's 90% of the width of the available space, up to a maximum of 960px, but that's dependent on its container being resizable itself. Responsive design is a whole big ball of wax though, so this doesn't even scratch the surface.

Answer (score 1):

`@media screen and (max-width : 760px)` (for tablets and phones) and use with this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`