# How to get excerpt text to automatically cut off at the bottom of a div

Tags: css, html

In this fiddle you see divs like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/tickzoom/gzREg/

```
<div class="excerpt">
    <div class="excerpt-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus
            scelerisque aliquet. Aenean tincidunt cursus adipiscing. Phasellus viverra
            facilisis tortor. Pellentesque interdum scelerisque eros, id auctor est
            porttitor at. Vestibulum semper lacus sed ipsum varius eu semper erat condimentum.
            </p>
    </div>
    <div class "excerpt-more">
        <p>Learn more</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And style like so:

```
.excerpt {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
.excerpt-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 5%;
}
.excerpt-more {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100% color: red;
}
```

Notice in the fiddle that the the lipsum text of the first div overruns the Learn More text in the second div.  The text needs to be bounded inside the the top div so that when the whole page is resized either more or less of text gets shown but the Learn More is always shown.

There must be something simple that I'm missing or doing wrong because I have a site where this works from a plugin on WordPress for the Genesis Framework called the Genesis Responsive Slider. The trouble with their plugin is that the "Learn More" link follows the text and so at smaller screens it disappears outside the bounding box.

So the plan is to introduce the second div to the plugin PHP code to protect the Learn More link from disappearing at smaller screen sizes.

If you want to see the temporary development site in question:  http://side.tickzoom.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLaSp/)

```
.excerpt-text {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then making the text size larger is then a different problem of resizing the height of `.excerpt-text`.

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZUJ4/)

```
.excerpt-text {
    height: 50%;
}
```

**EDIT:** Try removing the following rule

```
html > body .slide-excerpt-border {
    float: left;
}
```

Also you should remove `html > body` from this rule so it's just `.slide-excerpt-border`, the start part is redundant.

**EDIT:** While you were fixing it I did this

[image]

I added this:

```
.slide-excerpt-border {
    height: 95%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And moved the Learn Move anchor down below `.slide-excerpt-border`

Comment: Yes that works but with amik's warning of earlier browsers and that the site doesn't do it this way, how are they doing it? I'm using the Chrome browser developer tools to examine the CSS for the bounding divs, the p tag and can't see any overflow style.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` has been supported for a long time. It's `text-overflow` that isn't supported well (doesn't seem to work in Chrome).

Comment: If site.tickzoom.com is the reference you're working off it doesn't do this, Learn More gets pushed down and hidden.

Comment: Correct. That's what I want to fix. I want to add another div to keep the Learn More visible. But the site does make the text cut off at the bottom of the div. I can't figure out how to do that in the  jsfiddle site. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: in the Chrome browser (or FireFox plugins) it allows modifying the CSS on the fly. So I resized the screen very small and disabled the float: left on .slide-exceprt-border but the overflowing text was still hidden. (Scratching my head) How do they hide the overflow?

Comment: It's solved. You were right. It turns out the reference site has overflow: hidden on some higher bounding divs which is what cuts off the text. You helped me realize what to look for. So I'll have to do as you said and add overflow: hidden to my excerpt-text div. Thanks!

Comment: Very cool solution. The only issue is the relative 5% space for the Learn More. That will get squished at smaller screen sizes. My solution was to put the Learn More in a div with fixed pixel height. But now wondering how to make the upper div respect the bounding space.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.excerpt{text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

but check it works in all browsers you desire, it's a CSS3 property which haven't worked in most browsers not so long ago.

edit: Combination with overflow:hidden mentioned above may be the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Actually, cutting off the text already works on the site referenced at http://site.tickzoom.com but I can't figure out how to do that in my "fiddle".  The site doesn't have any "text-overflow" CSS that I can see.  Is there some other way that they're doing this maybe so it will be better browser compatibility? 

I do see that they use z-index: 8  but unclear how that will help with this and tried it didn't seem to do anything enabling or disabling that.

Comment: @Wayne It looks like the text is being cut off in the markup, not CSS.

Comment: @Tyriar It actually does both. The markup cuts off at 150 words. Then the CSS handles cutting it off when the screen is resized smaller.

Comment: You can't use `text-overflow` at multiline text!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use responsive media queries for different screen types.

here is an example and explanation how to use it http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

or there was another question about this

[Making div content responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632500/making-div-content-responsive)

Comment: You are probably on to something here because this reference WordPress site uses a theme that definitely is "responsive". I hope for some more specific help but I'll keep reading your links and maybe figure it out myself.

Comment: it turns out just using overflow hidden solved it. But this was very interesting reading about the media selectors. I will eventually need to use this.